# Rails cache will block the clients' request while they are making

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Prevent requests blocked by caching and auto regenerate fresh caches

We can easily make Rails `cache`, and set the expires time like that

```
Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 1.minute) do
    `fetch_data_from_mongoDB_with_complex_query`
end
```

Somehow, when the new request comes in, expiration happens, and the request will block.  My question is, how can I avoid that kind of situation?  Basically, I want to give the previous cache to client's request while Rails is making cache.

As shown in the the expected behaviour diagram, the second request will get the `cache 1` but not `cache 2`, although the Rails is making for the `cache 2`.  Therefore, the user won't have to spend much time on making new cache.  So, how can I automatically regenerate all the caches without users' request to trigger it?

## Expected  behaviour

[image]

## Cache snippet

```
     cache_key = "#{__callee__}"
     Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 1.hour) do
       all.order_by(updated_at: -1).limit(max_rtn_count)
     end
```

## Update

How could I get all the cached keys in a command ?

Because the cached query can be generate by the composition of `start_date`, `end_date`, `depature_at`, `arrive_at`.

It's not possible to invalidate all the cached keys manually.

How could I get the all cache keys, then refresh then in Rake task

Comment: You can't (easily) do this. This isn't how caching works in Rails. You would need to enqueue a job to run asynchronously to generate the new cache, and overwrite/modify some built-in methods like `cache`.

Comment: What are you caching?  Is it possible to use cache keys that update only when the result of what you're caching updates (thus circumventing the issue with the slow response)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `expiration` is tricky as once the cached object expires, you won't be able to fetch the expired value.

The best practice would be to decouple your cache-refreshing process from the end user traffic. You would need a rake task that populates/refreshes your cache and run that task as a cron. If for some reason, the job doesn't run, the cache would expire and your users will incur the additional time to fetch the data.

However, if your dataset is too large to refresh/load all of it at once, you'd have to use a different cache-expiration policy (You could update the expiration time after every cache-hit).

Alternatively, you could disable cache expiration and use a different indicator (such as time) to determine if the object in the cache is up to date or stale. If it is stale, you could use an asynchronous `ActiveJob` worker to queue a job to update the cache. The stale data will be returned to the user and the cache will be updated in the background.

Comment: Hi Thanks very much, so..do you mean that I could also put the expiration code in my controller and view `Rails.cache.fetch( cache_key, expires_in: 1.hour) do` ,  and on the other hand running a rake task to invalidate the cache  ? could you give me simple example or idea how to invalidate a cache after fetching data from DB manually ? thanks

Comment: No, the options I suggested are to: 1) Not set a cache expiration and keep updating the cache using a backend rake task  (`Rails.cache.write...`) or 2) Not set a cache expiration and use an async worker to update the cache (using sidekiq, etc). Using the `cache.write` method would overwrite the current object - no need for invalidation. Your rake task would update/overwrite the cache, not invalidate it. Use of expiration means that you WILL lose your object and re-fetch every time the cache expires.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, btw How could I get all the cached keys in a command ? i updated it .i think i almost fix my problem by your answer.

Comment: @newBike you're welcome. You could get a list of all the cached keys with `cache.instance_values["data"].keys`. If you can't easily invalidate the cached keys, consider creating them under a `cache.namespace` and invalidating the namespace. You can find examples in the [Cache::Store API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html)

Comment: Should I always create an namespace before creating an new cache ? because I get nothing with your suggestion  :(

Comment: No, the user defined namespace is just for convenience

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working how caching is designed to work. When the second request comes in, after `1hr` in your case, the query re-runs and blocks the request while the query is running.

What you want is for Rails to return a `cache1` the original expired cached while its working on generating the new `cache2`.

But think about what you are asking? You are asking it to return something which has expired? How could rails return `cache1`, when it has expired. This happened because you explicitly set the cache to expire in exactly 1 hour.

There could be many ways to achieve what you want, here is one solution which comes immediately to mind:

1. Run your long query and put its result along with current timestamp in your cache. Don't put any expiry on it.
2. Schedule a background job to re-run the above long query and update cache every 1 hour. Try to make the update atomic.
3. Now whenever a browser request comes in just return what's in the cache.